# Is the Deadpool origin story from the new movie (2016) sourced in the comics?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

I'm reasonably well versed in Wolverine's healing factor being extracted in Weapon X, given to Deadpool to cure his cancer, causing disfigurement, etc. I also know that there's a lot of varying origins throughout the books, and stuff like Thanos granting him immortality etc.

However, in the new Deadpool Movie:

> His healing comes from a mutation triggered in his own body under huge stress by some British guy running a shady organisation.

Is that sourced from the comics? Where's Weapon X? What?

I thought it was great, don't get me wrong, but I was surprised to be surprised with that part.

Comment: I think it's possible that Ajax may have been able to acquire and use Wolverine's healing factor and injected it into Wade as part of the process,  this is not mentioned in the move, nor is it confirmed so it's entirely speculation.

If he DID have Wolverine's healing power, wouldn't his skin have healed perfectly like Wolverine's does? or is that a side effect of it constantly battling his cancer?

In my opinion, it may be an entirely new direction of Wade's origin story that diverges from the known origin story due to the X-men universe reboot recently? Some sort of butterfly effect

Comment: They need to move away from the X Men Origins origin, as this movie was created entirely with the purpose of refuting it.

Comment: @JaradDucroq My own interpretation of [Deadpool's origin in the comics](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/43557/deadpool_and_death_annual_1998_1) is that the artificial healing factor didn't cure his cancer, but only keeps it from killing him. He looks like an overcooked pizza because the cancer has permeated his entire body. [Here's what he looked like just before his healing factor activated](http://smg.photobucket.com/user/foresthouse/media/Deadpool/Scans/DeadpoolDeathAnnual/DP_escape2.jpg.html)

Comment: @Blazemonger I agree with what you said, I just worded it poorly in the OP. But no comic source of the healing factor coming from his own mutation?

Comment: Correct: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Deadpool

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Deadpool first meets Ajax in Deadpool #14

The film seems,  more or less, faithful to (at least one of)  Deadpool's comic origins.

This is an excerpt from Wikipedia

> After endless taunting from Wilson, Francis was given permission by Killebrew to kill him. Francis orchestrated events so that Wilson would perform a mercy killing on another inmate, which was against the rules; the inmate Deadpool was to kill was one to whom he had grown particularly close. After Francis removed Wilson's heart, his healing factor manifested itself for the first time by regenerating a new heart for the mercenary.

Which fits what we see in the film. The same article discusses how Francis/Ajax is in charge of Weapon X drop outs.

Further wiki [reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool) reveals:

> The original story had him joining the Weapon X program after being kicked out of the United States Army Special Forces

Another similarity.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I hoped to find out about! I gave up hope of there being a source as the last answer was a month ago!

Answer (score 5):

In the X-Men Cinematic Universe, Wolverine's origin in the Weapon X program has been erased. It's possible the Weapon X program never happened in the new XCU timeline.

In "X-Men Origins: Wolverine", he and Sabretooth were both part of Stryker's Weapon X program. In the same movie, Wade Wilson was also part of the Weapon X program and was altered by Stryker into a very different "Weapon XI".

Then the "X-Men: Days of Future Past" movie rewrote everything, making this Deadpool movie possible. However, it also rewrote Wolverine's origin in an as-yet-unspecified manner. The last we saw Wolverine in the 1970s, he was rescued from the bottom of the Potomac River, nearly dead, and in the possession of Mystique posing as Stryker. In our future, Wolverine is still at Xavier's school, but it's not specified whether he has his adamantium claws by then or not.

[According to IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3385516/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast), Stryker is in the upcoming movie "X-Men: Apocalypse", but Logan/Wolverine is not. So it's questionable whether we'll get a definitive answer to what happened to Logan between those two films.

This being the case, it's possible the writers of "Deadpool" decided to play it safe and disentangle Wade from the Weapon X program entirely. That way, they didn't have to worry about contradicting the upcoming "X-Men: Apocalypse" film.